# SQL require literal value in foreign column

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

Is it possible to require a specific literal value in a foreign key constraint?

For example

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id bigserial primary key,
  b_id bigint not null,
  foreign key (b_id, true) references b(id, flag)
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id bigserial primary key,
  flag boolean
);
```

where we want to require that rows in `a` reference only rows in `b` with a flag set to `true`.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Maybe you can add a helper column to be and set value as _id or null and have a FK in A that reference the helper column in B

Answer (score 3):

The syntax in the question is not valid (see [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)). You can get the desired effect as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
    id bigserial,
    flag boolean,
    primary key(id, flag)
);

CREATE TABLE a (
    id bigserial primary key,
    b_id bigint not null,
    flag boolean default true check (flag),
    foreign key (b_id, flag) references b(id, flag)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want something along these lines. I did away with the superfluous `a.id` column to make it easier to read.

```
CREATE TABLE b (
  id bigserial not null,
  flag boolean not null,
  primary key (id),
  unique (id, flag)
);
```

The primary key constraint on `id` prevents duplicate id numbers. The overlapping constraint on `id, flag` allows this *pair* of columns to be the target of a foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  b_id bigint not null,
  flag boolean not null default true
    check (flag = true),
  primary key (b_id, flag),
  foreign key (b_id, flag) references b (id, flag)
    on delete cascade
);
```

In order for a row in `a` to reference *only* those rows in `b` where `flag` is true, every row in `a` *must* have `flag` set to true. The default and the check constraint on `flag` guarantees that.

Now let's try inserting some rows.

```
insert into b (flag) values (true);
insert into b (flag) values (true);
insert into b (flag) values (false);
```

So far, so good. Now some rows for a.

```
insert into a (b_id, flag) values (1, true);
insert into a (b_id, flag) values (2, true);
```

But this one should fail.

```
insert into a (b_id, flag) values (3, true);

--ERROR:  insert or update on table "a" violates foreign key constraint "a_b_id_fkey"
--DETAIL:  Key (b_id, flag)=(3, t) is not present in table "b".
```

And this one should fail.

```
insert into a (b_id, flag) values (3, false);

--ERROR:  new row for relation "a" violates check constraint "a_flag_check"
--DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, f).
```

**One more thing**

You need to think about what you want to happen when you update a flag in table b. You can't cascade updates; that would result in a row in `a` referencing a row that has `false` in b.

```
update b set flag = false where id = 1 and flag = true;
-- ERROR:  update or delete on table "b" violates foreign key constraint "a_b_id_fkey" on table "a"
-- DETAIL:  Key (id, flag)=(1, t) is still referenced from table "a".
```

How you deal with that is application-dependent. In some apps, it might be appropriate to delete the row in `a` when the row in `b` updates to `false`. In other apps, it might be appropriate to just revoke update permissions on `b`. (There are other options.) In any case, you'll need to write a trigger.